# Problema al usar case en switch JS

Tags: javascript, switch

Quiero que al introducir los datos de 3 notas, estas hagan una media según un rango, menos que 5 de suspenso, mayor o igual que 5 aprobado, mayor o igual que 7 notable y mayor o igual que 9 sobresaliente. No entiendo porque el case de switch no verifica la función que le pido. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, un saludo.

```
    <script>
    let nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es nombre?");
    let nota = prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?");
    let nota0 = prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?");
    let nota1 = prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?");
    let notamedia = parseInt(nota + nota0 + nota1);
    let notamedia0 = parseInt(notamedia / 3)
    switch (notamedia0) {
        case notamedia0 < 5:
            document.write('Suspenso');
            break;
    }
    switch (notamedia0) {
        case notamedia0 >= 5:
            document.write('Suspenso');
            break;
    }
    switch (notamedia0) {
        case notamedia0 > 7 < 9:
            document.write('Suspenso');
            break;
    }
    switch (notamedia0) {
        case notamedia0 >=9 :
            document.write('Suspenso');
            break;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tal vez esta entrada te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464362/javascript-using-a-condition-in-switch-case

Comment: ¿Porqué usar `switch case` en vez de una estructura `if else`? Además, la forma en que estás implementando los casos no es la adecuada ya que usas un `switch` por cada uno. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes parsear a entero el **prompt**, no la suma de las cadenas recogidas en los prompts supuestamente numéricos.

Y también puedes usar el switch, validando las condiciones que son `true` en cada `case` tal como ves en el código siguiente:

Compruébalo ejecutando este snippet con las correcciones:

```js
let nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es nombre?");
let nota = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?"));
let nota0 = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?"));
let nota1 = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?"));
let notamedia = (nota + nota0 + nota1) / 3;
switch (true) {
  case (notamedia < 5):
    evaluacion = 'Suspenso'
    break;
  case ((notamedia >= 5) && (notamedia < 7)):
    evaluacion = 'Aprobado'  
    break;
  case ((notamedia >= 7) && (notamedia < 9)):
    evaluacion = 'Notable'
    break;
  case (notamedia >= 9):
    evaluacion = 'Sobresaliente'  
    break;
}
document.write(nombre + ': Has sacado un ' + evaluacion + ': Nota media: ' + notamedia );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro. Si consideras que esta respuesta satisface a tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que no quede pendiente para siempre.

Comment: Ya está, disculpa. Estoy empezando en StackOverflow y algunas pautas las desconozco. Un saludo.

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que pases por el [tour] que son dos minutos de lectura rápida para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y asi colaborar mejor con la comunidad, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Lo podrías solventar de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
    let nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es nombre?");
    let nota = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?"));
    let nota0 = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?"));
    let nota1 = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuál es tu nota de ?"));
    let notamedia = parseInt((nota + nota0 + nota1) / 3);

    let mensaje = 'Suspenso';

    if (notamedia >= 9) {
        mensaje = 'Sobresaliente';
    }
    else if (notamedia > 7) {
        mensaje = 'Notable';
    }
    else if (notamedia >= 5) {
        mensaje = 'Aprobado';
    }

    document.write(mensaje);
</script>
```

Comment: El ejercicio me exige usar switch, aún así gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Sin problema, te puse el ejemplo con if porque en tu pregunta no indicabas que debías usar switch.

Comment: Sí. Me expliqué muy mal, fallo mío. Disculpa las molestias y gracias por tu respuesta.